# OpenGl картинка отображается кверху ногами

Tags: изображения, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте! Есть функция для отрисовки картинки:

```
void window::drawImage(int num, int w, int h, int x, int y){ 
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[num]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(x+w, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(x+w, y+h, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, y+h, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Но картинка отображается кверху ногами. Что не так?

Comment: возможно, у вас вершины полигона перевернуты

Comment: Как исправить?

Comment: новые (перевернутые, отрицательные) координаты передать полигону после строки glBegin(GL_QUADS); координаты не помню у opengl точка отчета в правом нижнем углу по моему находится могу ошибатся

Comment: Как это делается? Извини, я совсем еще нуб

Comment: Я сам новичок. Тебе надо книгу вот эту почитать http://www3.msiu.ru/~kupri-ov/Books/RedBook_OpenGL.pdf

Comment: Ответить на вопрос нельзя, не зная (1) как настроены видовая матрица и матрица проекции, (2) как вызывается метод drawImage. Метод drawImage, вероятно, написан неправильно, так как сперва система координат переносится на x, y в glTranslatef, а затем часть вершин зачем-то сдвинута в glVertex3f на эти же x, y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);          // Рисуем куб
// Передняя грань
glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Нормаль указывает на наблюдателя
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f); // Точка 1 (Перед)
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f); // Точка 2 (Перед)
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f); // Точка 3 (Перед)
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f); // Точка 4 (Перед)

glEnd();                // Закончили квадраты
```